# extending UIImagePicker controller doesn't help to prevent rotation in io6

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

My application is set in info.plist to support only portrait mode.

However, the UIImagePickerController, rotates when the user rotates the screen to landscape.

Since in io6 the method shouldAutoRotate is not being called, I tried to extend it like this:

```
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

But it doesn't help. Any idea why?

And in the log I see the above methods being called. The UIImagePickerController at first is displayed in portrait and when the user rotates - it rotates as well instead of staying portrait.

I set the image picker in the view like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (!self.imagePickerController) {
        self.imagePickerController = [[NonRotatingUIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
   CGRect imagePickerControllerFrame = CGRectMake(0, topBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - topBar.frame.size.height - bottomBar.frame.size.height);
   self.imagePickerController.view.frame = imagePickerControllerFrame;
   self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
   self.imagePickerController.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
  self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
  [self.view.window addSubview:self.imagePickerController.view];
}
```

Comment: Can you show code to prove that you are actually using this class?

Comment: done. Please note that I add the image picker as a sub view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.imagePickerController.view.frame = imagePickerControllerFrame;
// ...
[self.view.window addSubview:self.imagePickerController.view];
```

Well, that's all totally illegitimate. Apple makes this very clear in the docs:

> This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified

There is only one correct way to use an image picker controller that uses UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera - as a fullscreen presented view controller:

```
BOOL ok = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
           UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
if (!ok) {
    NSLog(@"no camera");
    return;
}
NSArray* arr = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
                UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
if ([arr indexOfObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage] == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"no stills");
    return;
}
UIImagePickerController* picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want to present a live picture-taking interface *inside* your *own* interface, use AVFoundation and the camera capture API that it gives you.

Downloadable working example here:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/ch30p816cameraCaptureWithAVFoundation/p683cameraCaptureWithAVFoundation/ViewController.m

Comment: I tried creating it as full screen - and it still rotates, although the my app is defined in info.plist for Portrait mode only. Does that mean that in order to disable rotation I have to use AVFoundation interface?

Comment: On iPad, it is rotatable and there's nothing you can do about that. (That might be a bug, but I don't know; you could try filing a bug on it.) But the bottom line is: It's not your view. It's not your view controller. Use it as is or roll your own using AVFoundation.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why Apple provides such a limited implementation for the UIImagePickerController

Comment: File a bug requesting an enhancement. But whether you like it or not, you should obey the docs. You certainly should not disobey the docs and then complain that things are working oddly.

Comment: Thanks. I am using your code - but how do I prevent the camera from rotating? I would like it to be only in Portrait mode and take pictures only in portrait

Comment: Grab the user's hands and keep him from rotating the device? :) Seriously, that's a completely different question. Up to now you were asking about the picture-taking interface. Now you're asking about the user's interaction with the *hardware*.

Comment: Not really! this was my whole question about - how to make the camera not rotated - take pictures only in portrait mode ! you suggested to use AVFoundation but didn't define how to solve the real problem ":(

Comment: What I'm telling you is that in that case you failed to ask the question coherently, as your question doesn't say at all that this is "the real problem". I'm suggesting that you now ask a different question and this time ask the question you really want to know the answer to.

Comment: I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750887/disable-taking-images-in-any-orientation-other-than-portrait-avfoundation

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'll consider this answer unhelpful; but I'll just paste a snippet from Apple's documentation:

> Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

[UIImagePickerController Doc Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Sorry to be a kill-joy.  You should look for a replacement class.  Quickie search shows there are a bunch.